# Adding new data to mySQL database through PHP from iOS textfield

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, post

Still a noob with this stuff but here goes..
I'm trying to add a new player (that the user inputs in a textfield in iOS)  to a mySQL database.
I know there are similar questions on here already but I've tried everything and still cannot get it to work!

Here is the method in Xcode:

```
-(IBAction)Register:(id)sender {

    NSString *newPlayer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PlayerName=%@", _inputPlayerName.text];
    NSData *data = [newPlayer dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domainName.com/NewPlayer.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", returnString);
}
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","UserName","Password","DatabaseName");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO TableName (PlayerName) VALUES('$_POST[PlayerName]')";

mysql_query($con,$sql);

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The responseData in NSLog is coming back as blank.
If anyone can see where I've gone wrong I would be very grateful! Are there delegates or anything I need to assign?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed it now. The issue was lying somewhere within the variables I was using (I had about 20 lol). Incorrect syntax was also lurking..